# Chrome scaling issue while using rem units

Tags: css, google-chrome, scaling

we want to make everything on our website sized to 90% of actual proportions (luck we are using rem units), so the easiest solution for us is to write `html { font-size: 0.9rem; }` rule. However, we are facing some bugs with scaling in chrome - some elements have greater margin the other, not precise width/height etc. It works great in Safari and Firefox... you can see the example here in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0nvy4kt/2/), some buttons have undesirable last 1px height white line instead of background.

**edit**: well it seems to occur on retina display only

**edit 2**: I've updated chrome from 72 to 73 and it's okay now

[image]

Comment: works fine for me in chrome.

Comment: hm ... weird ... maybe the problem is related to retina display?

Comment: @MikelFerreiro oh cmon ... I've updated chrome from 72 to 73 and it's okay now...

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to write things like `html {font-size: 0.9rem;}`. The rem is the size of the html element (r stands for root), so you're basically saying that a rem is equal to 0.9 of a rem.

Comment: @MrLister so you would use `font-size: 90%` instead? It doesn't seem to behave differently.

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes with your background. Change it to '#ff0000', and the gap goes away.

If you change your gradient to 'background-image', and then add 'background-color'; your problem appears to be fixed:

```
.button.primary {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fac364 0%, #fabe53 50%, #ffb433 100%);
    background-color: #fac364;
    border: 0;
}
```

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kcazfps8/

Comment: It's issue with scaling ... I've had problems also with other elements which were not respecting their dimensions and which weren't pixel perfect.

Comment: It seems updating the version of Chrome fixes the issue - it might still be worth applying this as a fall-back for users that don't have the latest browser version?

Comment: Well you know I mentioned this is not the only one issue in our app while we do scaling ... and we haven't got resources to do some fallbacks for each ui component.